# border color around selected dates in calendar in visual studio for the web 2012 using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

using asp.net in c# I want to be able to put a border color around the selected dates in a calendar. I am able to put a border around each cell however I want to be able to put a border around a few dates.

Also the calendar that I am using is the basic one in the toolbars option (calendar control).

The code that I am using so far to put a border around one cell is shown below:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (dsHolidays != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dsHolidays.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            DateTime nextDate;
            DateTime endDate;

            nextDate = (DateTime)dr["date"];
            endDate = (DateTime)dr["date1"];

            if (nextDate <= e.Day.Date && endDate >= e.Day.Date)
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                e.Cell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
                e.Cell.BorderWidth = 4;
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: are you using the standard .NET Calendar control?

Comment: Yes the one on Microsoft visual studio express 2012 for web.

Comment: If you will edit your question to say that, then I'll remove my downvote. You should also add a little more context to your code. In particular, what is `e`? Is this code inside an event handler? Which handler? Please show the signature of the handler method (`protected void Calendar_SomeEvent(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)`).

Comment: Hi   I have added the handler if there is more code you need just ask. Also I am new to asp.net c sharp.   Thanks

Comment: Ok, and that's "C#", not "C Sharp" :-)

Comment: Downvote removed. Thanks.

Comment: Is this c# or C Sharp?

Comment: Also the database that I am using is SQL Server 2012, if this helps. Thanks